# include changes sizeof in_addr in struct

Tags: c

Ok, I've got a struct containing a `struct in_addr` element.
This should make struct `addrlist_t` at least **12 Bytes in size (8 + 4)**. The platform is `amd64`.

```
#include <netinet/in.h> // struct in_addr
#include <stdio.h> // printf()
#include <netdb.h> // toggles size of struct addrlist_t

struct addrlist_t {
    struct addrlist_t *next;
    struct in_addr h_addr;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    printf("%zu + %zu = %zu\n",
        sizeof (struct addrlist_t *), sizeof (struct in_addr), 
        sizeof (struct addrlist_t)
    );
    return 0;
}
```

This is the totally unexpected output:

```
$cc main.c -o main -Wall -Wwrite-strings -pedantic -std=gnu99 -Wall -Werror
$./main
8 + 4 = 8
```

This seems to make no sense. The combined size should be at least 12, not smaller!

But now, when `#include &lt;netdb.h&gt;` is removed, the expected output appears:

```
$./main
8 + 4 = 16
```

The same things happens when `-std=gnu99` is replaced by `-std=c99`.

Can someone explain this behavior?

For completeness:

```
$file main
main: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=709ab89d012d8b5a6ae7423fd80ce643288cba95, not stripped
```

Edit: formatting / words

Comment: @Gopi No, since the OP's result is *smaller* than the sum. It seems very magical. I ran it on ideone in C99 mode, that printed `4 + 4 = 8` (I guess they have 32-bit environments).

Comment: `#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L`, without it I can repro your output with clang 3.5 x64 on Mac OS X 10.10. With it, its 16, as expected.

Comment: You were so close to finding it yourself :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is because you have an unfortunate name for the `struct in_addr h_addr` member.

`<netdb.h>` in glibc contains this:

```
# define    h_addr  h_addr_list[0] /* Address, for backward compatibility.*/
```

Run gcc -E main.c to see how your code looks after preprossessing,
your struct addrlist_t essentially becomes this:

```
struct addrlist_t {
    struct addrlist_t *next;
    struct in_addr h_addr_list[0];
};
```

Which is a very different thing from what you intended.

Comment: Ooah .. nice catch! :-) I love the pre-processor for such subtile actions ...;->

Comment: The surrounding lines in that header may well jive with my findings regarding POSIX feature macros, [posted here](http://pastebin.com/uPt9hY5U) for reference (its Darwin/clang btw).

Comment: Thanks, this issues gave me some serious head scratching

Comment: @mwarming I would suggest defining _POSIX_C_SOURCE (and/or _XOPEN_SOURCE) with an appropriate value at the top of your file, before including any headers - that's what it's for, and technically you have no guarantee of what the default configuration is when it is not defined.